# Everything I do is either over-complicated or wrong

Tags: java

```
// *************************************************************
//   Distance.java
//   Computes the distance between two points in java
// *************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Distance
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        double x1, y1, x2, y2; // coordinates of two points
        double distance;      // distance between the points

        //Formula -   D=√(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read in the two points
        System.out.print ("Enter the coordinates of the first point " +
                "(put a space between them): ");

        x1 = scan.nextDouble();
        y1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.print ("Enter the coordinates of the second point: ");
        x2 = scan.nextDouble();
        y2 = scan.nextDouble();

        // Compute the distance
        double math = x1-x2 * y1-y2;

        // Print out the answer
        System.out.print("The distance between (" + x1 + "," + x2 + ") and (" + y1 + "," + y2 + ") is") ;
    }
}
```

I keep running into errors and I go on forever with codes that can be done faster and shorter. All I need to do is read the user input for coordinates, find the distance between them, and print the answer.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: This "question" is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea No it is not. The code in this question does not accomplish it's task and is thus considered "broken" by CR standards and accordingly off-topic. Please read the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before recommending Codereview to askers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First you create your Point Class. Remember this is Java and OOP

```
   class Point {

        private double x;
        private double y;
        private String name;

        public Point(String n, double xx, double yy) {
             this.name = n;
             this.x = xx;
             this.y = yy;
        }

        public double getX() {
             return this.x;
        }

        public double getY() {
             return this.y;
        }

        public String getName() {
             return this.name;
        }

   }
```

Secondly you create your Distance class with the distance calculating method

```
   public double getEuclideanDistance(Point p, Point q) {
        double ed = Math.sqrt((q.getX() - p.getX()) * (q.getX() - p.getX()) + (q.getY() - p.getY()) * (q.getY() - p.getY()));
        return ed;
   }
```

Lastly modify you main method as below

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         double Xp;
         double Yp;
         double Xq;
         double Yq;

         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter x- cordinate of P : ");
         Xp = reader.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Enter y- cordinate of P : ");
         Yp = reader.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Enter x- cordinate of Q : ");
         Xq = reader.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Enter y- cordinate of Q : ");
         Yq = reader.nextDouble();

         Point q = new Point("Q", Xq, Yq);
         Point p = new Point("P", Xp, Yp);

         System.out.println("Point " + p.getName() + "'s Coordinates are: " + "P(" + p.getX() + " , " + p.getY() + ")");
         System.out.println("Point " + q.getName() + "'s Coordinates are: " + "Q(" + q.getX() + " , " + q.getY() + ")");

         System.out.println("The Euclidean distance from p to q is :" + getEuclideanDistance(p, q));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not quite implementing the distance formula the correct way... you have `double math = x1-x2 * y1-y2` but aren't calling `Math.pow()` or `Math.sqrt()` at all.

Try to implement the following:

[image]

Comment: And the formula is wrong anyway, as normal operator precedence applies in the absence of parentheses.

Comment: How do you know what they are asking?

Comment: The commment says `Computes the distance between two points in java`... how could you not know what he's asking?

Comment: `All I need to do is read the user input for coordinates, find the distance between them, and print the answer.`

Comment: But he isn't saying what his problem is. He has just plonked a bunch of code.

Comment: Well @AntonyD'Andrea we can clearly see he has his input correctly setup so wouldn't, logically, the next thing to look at be his formula? Notably biziclop but we clearly see he hasn't quite implemented the formula the correct way.

Comment: Be clear though, by `^2` you mean "to raise to the power of 2."  By itself this might confuse a newcomer, because ^ is itself the bitwise XOR operator.  As this poor person discovered: http://stackoverflow.com, /questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java , and the square brackets are also confusing.  Newbies tend to think literally.

Comment: Fair enough. I am not trying to cause a conflict.